# How to fetch status of specific crowdloan using polkadot{.js} API?

Tags: polkadot-js, crowdloan

I'm trying to fetch the stats (amount raised, remaining time) of specific crowdloan using Polkadot.js API however I can't find any examples or docs explaining the `crowdloan` queries.

It is certainly possible as Polkadot.js app shows this under
[/apps/#/parachains/crowdloan](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/parachains/crowdloan) path.

Anyone has example how to get this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for example you are interested in fetching the stats you mentioned for the paraId = 2037 in Polkadot, then you could try running the following example code in [Polkadot-js apps > Developer menu > Javascript submenu](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.polkadot.io#/js) :

```
const paraInfo = await api.query.crowdloan.funds(2037);
console.log(JSON.stringify(paraInfo, null, 4));
```

and it will give you the following result :

```
{
    "depositor": "14bEKMdGLwGKNTz4BtT7venXZ4RcXdGfBSdEYrJLPNoHRvoK",
    "verifier": null,
    "deposit": 5000000000000,
    "raised": "0x0000000000000000001b1201976cc6ed",
    "end": 10881401,
    "cap": "0x00000000000000000214e8348c4f0000",
    "lastContribution": {
        "ending": 9829425
    },
    "firstPeriod": 8,
    "lastPeriod": 15,
    "fundIndex": 31
}
```

I think you are interested in the values associated with the keys `raised` and `end` ?

Comment: Thanks! Let me try that!

Comment: This worked perfectly! Is there any link to docs where this is documented?

Comment: It is not documented but we are thinking of adding some queries related to `parachains` and `crowdloans`. Until then, when you face a similar issue, you could try searching in `polkadot-js api` repo with keywords related to your question. In this case if you search with keywords `crowdloan info` or `crowdloan query` the result is this line `https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/3ded30a0f308b5954bd9c2c0ff91abf81a273d67/packages/api-derive/src/crowdloan/childKey.ts#L38` which gives you the actual query you need to do. Or you can always post a question here and someone will be happy to help :)